# USE shared <table> vs. USE <table> SHARED

Tags: shared, visual-foxpro, foxpro

My question is simple, when using a table in Visual Fox Pro, what's the difference between using shared before and after the table?

I was trying to use this to test an app I was building and when I wrote it before the table name it turned blue but not caps and the app couldn't use the table at the same time VFP was using it. Then I moved it to the end and it stayed blue but went all caps and the app could use it.

Comment: The SHARED keyword must come after the table name. The same is true for all the other modifiers of the USE command.

Comment: @TamarE.Granor If you add that as an answer I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SHARED keyword must come after the table name. The same is true for all the other modifiers of the USE command.